# <FB: LIKE tag is not posting "like" to facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

Our facebook like button is coded like this:

```
<fb:like href="http://url_to_page" font="arial" action="like" show_faces="false"
width="400" layout="button_count" send="false"></fb:like>
```

It has been working for years but suddenly stopped.

I checked the javascript console for errors but none are apparent. Everything looks as though it should work - but it does not.

I also searched for any info on changes to the facebook "like" tag recently.

My question is - does anyone know if facebook changed anything or is there anything that can conflict with the facebook tag but not throw an error.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: generate the code here, it includes all the necessary and updated code: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button

Comment: If that is the only code you added that will never had worked.